# parsing actual link from href using lxml

Tags: python, parsing, lxml

Using jupyter notebook, python 3.
I'm downloading some files from the web, much with them in bulk locally. The files are listed on a webpage, but they are in an href attribute. The code I found gives me the text, but not the actual link (even though my understanding is the code was supposed to get the link).

Here's what I have:

```
import os
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
...
web_string = requests.get(url).content
parsed_content = html.fromstring(web_string)
td_list = [e for e in parsed_content.iter() if e.tag == 'td']

directive_list = []
for td_e in td_list:
   txt = td_e.text_content()
   
   directive_list.append(txt)
```

This is a long web page with a bunch of entries that look like
`<a href="file1.pdf"> text1 </a>`

This code returns: text1, text2, etc. instead of file1.pdf, file2.pdf

How can I extract the link?

Comment: `href` is what's called an "attribute" (of the anchor `a`), not text content.

Comment: You need to select the `a` element, not `td`. Then use `element.attrib['href']`

Comment: You can use XPath to find all the `a` elements, rather than iterating over all elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify your code to specifically look for `a` elements within each `td` and extract their `href` attribute.

```
import requests
from lxml import html

url = 'YOUR_URL_HERE'  # Replace with your URL
web_string = requests.get(url).content
parsed_content = html.fromstring(web_string)

# Find all 'a' elements inside 'td' elements
links = parsed_content.xpath('//td/a')

directive_list = []
for link in links:
    # Get the href attribute
    href = link.get('href')

    # You might want to join this with the base URL if they are relative links
    # href = urllib.parse.urljoin(url, href)

    directive_list.append(href)

# Print the list of links
print(directive_list)
```